# Make Wildfly console log subsystem messages without wrapping in the root logger

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, log4j2

I use Wildfly to launch a single JEE application and all subsystem logs appear to be wrapped inside the root logger under INFO, regardless of their intended level.

Example:

*15:35:54,357 **INFO** [stdout] (default task-1) 2023-02-08 15:35:54 782b3ed6-0a93-4d30-a4fc-eaf7932840b0 **WARN** com.mycompany.MyResource:45 - [OK] - GET /v1/call*

As you can see INFO is the root logger and WARN is the intended level. This is a huge issue when these logs get queried by LogDNA as everything appears in INFO and I can't filter by level.

I tried setting the pattern to:

```
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

from:

```
<formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
</formatter>
```

And it kinda works, but also makes LogDNA misinterpret a good portion of the logs, not linking them to the service, but rather the underlying pods. No idea how and why.

Any help in configuring Wildfly and Log4j2 to specify the correct log level or not print subsystem logs through the root logger would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: It appears the LogDna issues are not related to the pattern, but still, using pattern="%s%e%n" does not log enough information on container log events.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you using?

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins, I am using wildfly-26.0.0.Final

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a separate log4j2 configuration? If not, you could simply remove log4j-core and the configuration file from your deployment and it should log to the console with the same pattern.

Comment: I am not sure what configuration you are referring to. Those settings are in standalone.xml

Comment: Those settings are yes, but something is logging to `stdout` as you can see with the `15:35:54,357 INFO [stdout]` snippet. This means you likely have some other logging configuration file in your deployment with a console handler/appender defined.